# When I leave my application, my icon launcher is still focused (surrounded with a blue line)

Tags: android, android-activity, focus, libgdx, app-launcher

I've been having an inconvenience when I quit my game using the libgdx frameworks Gdx.app.exit(), I return to my phone home screen but my game icon launcher is still focused (surrounded by a blue line). I would like it not to be focused anymore when I exit my game.
How can I achieve this ?

Thank you

Comment: that never happened to me....when ever i try to close using gdx.app.exit() it does come out and there is no focus over the icon launcher....do check it again else u can always use the System.exit(0); also basic java commands to exit out of the app.
hope this helped you

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your app is still running in background with your phone when you exit.

It's not recommended to use Gdx.app.exit(), and you should know that it's not important to create this function in your game,.. almost every Android apps don't have an exit button, it's to the user to end the task manually.

check this link to understand more: [Libgdx app.exit() on Android not closing application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508769/libgdx-app-exit-on-android-not-closing-application/12516298#12516298)