# Scrambled textures on Android

Tags: android, libgdx

Yes, I know, this question has been asked before. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508769/libgdx-app-exit-on-android-not-closing-application) and some other answers but still can't get the right way.

I have a small game application with, let we say, two screens - MainMenu and GameScreen. The skin is created from scratch in the main class (my MainGameClass). Then I pass a reference to the main class to every screen and with **getSkin** I have reference. In the MenuScreen, on backPress I do **Gdx.app.exit()** disposing the skin and everything works fine. The problem is if I use home button in the GameScreen that should load the game content with a board and the board has some images. After restarting the game all the textures look awful.

Well. What I've done?
First I had a singleton SkinManager with non-static skin. Bad.

Then I've tried to put only the needed skin part in every class. Same result.

Right now I call **dispose()** in every **hide()** method in the screens to clean all the references to the skin/textures every time I change the screen. Every time I call **getSkin()** I dispose it before creating but still nothing works.

MainClass:

```
public Skin getSkin() {
    skin.dispose();
    createSkin();
    return skin;
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    skin.dispose();
}
```

MainMenu:

```
    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);

    InputProcessor backProcessor = new InputAdapter() {
        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            if ((keycode == Keys.ESCAPE) || (keycode == Keys.BACK) ) {
                dispose();
                Gdx.app.exit();
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Then:

```
@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    skin.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
}
```

GameScreen:

```
@Override
public void resume() {
    skin = ((MainClass) game).getSkin();
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    board.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
}
```

When I try to switch to the MainMenu again I can't call dispose, this throws an exception like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: buffer not allocated with newUnsafeByteBuffer or already disposed
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BufferUtils.disposeUnsafeByteBuffer(BufferUtils.java:278)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.VertexArray.dispose(VertexArray.java:71)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.dispose(Mesh.java:673)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.dispose(SpriteBatch.java:1099)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.dispose(Stage.java:715)
    at com.xxx.yyy.screens.GameScreen.dispose(GameScreen.java:315)
```

and line 315 is **stage.dispose()** inside dispose method so I've commented it.

Inside my Board class I've created dispose method like this:

```
public void dispose() {
        boardSkin.dispose();
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++) {
                // dispose the skin references for every object and texture objects on the board
            }
        }
    }
```

What I'm doing bad? What to do to avoid texture scrambling? I realy need help.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you disposing of and recreating your skin every time `getSkin()` is called? The problem is probably related to this unusual method of managing your skin. Textures are automatically managed. Create your skin in the `create` method, and dispose it in the `dispose` method, and everything else should be handled for you.   The only reason I can think of to dispose of it elsewhere is if you are planning to not use it in a certain scene and need to reclaim the memory.

Comment: No, sorry @Tenfour04, but the textures are not disposed. In fact they are, but there is a reference to the java object that is not "cleaned" from the android activity. That is the difference between java and gdx objects and the scope they persist. The link in the begining of my post explains this. I did what you say but the behaviour is incorrect. I've got scrambled textures after resuming my android activity. Thank you for trying it, but, believe me, this doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you not using an asset manager to manage your assets automatically?

Comment: I do believe you. I'm saying that your unusual handling of the `dispose` method may be contributing to your issue. You are calling `getSkin` in your `resume` method, and your `getSkin` method is calling `skin.dispose`, and you are trying to recreate your skin in resume. I don't know what's in your `createSkin` method, but something tells me you should only be calling it from your Game's `create` method.

Comment: Calling dispose before create was a desperate try to remove all the existing reference to the skin, nothing useful. just killing all. Create method is creating the skin from scratch - putting textures, fonts etc.

Comment: @Jyro117, I don't understand very well the AsetManager. There everything is loaded from files (or I am wrong) and I need images but also I use lot of simple Pixmaps. And this is the problem - in my skin everything is fine except the pixmaps. My images are loaded correctly but the pixmaps are scrambled. Why?

Comment: You need to reload the textures based on the Pixmaps, since when Android resumes the graphics memory is purged. One way to do this is take your Pixmap based textures and call texture.load(texture.getTextureData());

Comment: @Jyro117, thank you for the tip. I've tried to load/reload the textures on game resume - nothing. Making static textures, keeping TextureData etc. - nothing. After reading [this] (http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Textures) tried to make the skin and the textures static and rebuild all the skin on resume. Same result. I made a singleton SkinManager - absolutly nothig. I always got bad Pixmap textures. I'm prety sure I'm doing something bad but I have no idea how to get better results. I'm thinking of make 1px pixmap of the desired color and load managed textures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll explain how I did the things and what worked for me. Probably this is not the best way but this is what don't give me much problems.

First - the skin, public and static, is created in my Main application class and it's recreated on resume:

```
public class MainClass{

    public static Skin skin;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        ...
        createSkin();
        ...
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        skin.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        createSkin();
    }

    public static void createSkin() {
        skin = new Skin();

        // all the textures from images:
        Texture texture1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture1.img"));
        skin.add("texture1", texture1);

        ...
    }

}
```

In my screens the skin is accessed by:

```
MainClass.skin.bla-bla-bla;
```

In the android activity the skin is recreated on restart:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        MainClass.createSkin();
    }
}
```

As I said, not very elegant, may be there is a better way, but this worked.